# Snap to anchor point animation

Tags: javascript

I'm using a [great plugin](http://benoit.pointet.info/stuff/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin/) that snaps to an anchor point when scrolling within the specified proximity. However, I would like to add animation to this effect but can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the best code I could come up with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).scrollsnap({
        snaps: '.snap',
        proximity: 200,
        }, 300,"easeInOutExpo");
    });
</script>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: From the page you linked to: `Note that this plugin just implements the vertical snapping logic and provides no styling.` What else could 'styling' mean then animating in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/benoitpointet/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin/blob/master/src/jquery.scrollsnap.js), it looks like it will attempt to animate the snap as long as you instantiate the plug-in using an element rather than the document itself:

```
$(scrollingEl).animate({scrollTop: (matchingEl.offsetTop + settings.offset)}, 200);
```

Therefore, I would suggest instantiating it with a reference to your page's top-level element instead.

The duration and easing are hardcoded as you can see from the above, but it will be easy enough to amend the plug-in code to allow you to dynamically set these properties via the plug-in settings if you need to.